# creating different dataset array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create different dataset based on month value. For eg. for June month one dataset and for July another dataset. But in my code, all the month values are getting combined and created as one dataset.

It will be really helpful who can help me in creating different dataset dynamically. I have attached the fiddle which I tried with my data object

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dxacxL6z/)

```
var obj = [{
    date: "2017-06-01",
    reqC: "129963",
    month: "JUNE",
    resC: "80522"
  }, {
    date: "2017-06-05",
    reqC: "261162",
    month: "JUNE",
    resC: "83743"
  },{
    date: "2017-07-03",
    reqC: "438860",
    month: "JULY",
    resC: "166107"
  }]
  var maindataset = [];
  var dataset = [];
 ["reqC", "resC"].forEach((series) => {
    dataset.push({
      seriesname: series,
      data: obj.map((el) => {
        return el[series]
      })
    })

  });
  maindataset.push({
    dataset: dataset
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(maindataset));

// Expected Output  

{
  "dataset": [
    {
      "dataset": [                 //June
        {
          "seriesname": "Req",   
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "129963"
            },
            {
              "value": "261162"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Res",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "80522"
            },
            {
              "value": "83743"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dataset": [                   //July
        {
          "seriesname": "Req",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "438860"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Res",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "166107"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested hash table and iterate later the keys for the wanted parts.

```js
var data = [{ date: "2017-06-01", reqC: "129963", month: "JUNE", resC: "80522" }, { date: "2017-06-05", reqC: "261162", month: "JUNE", resC: "83743" }, { date: "2017-07-03", reqC: "438860", month: "JULY", resC: "166107" }],
    result = { dataset: [] },
    parts = { reqC: 'Req', resC: 'Res' },
    hash = { _: result.dataset };

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var temp = hash;
    if (!temp[a.month]) {
        temp[a.month] = { _: [] };
        temp._.push({ dataset: temp[a.month]._ });
    }
    temp = temp[a.month];
    Object.keys(parts).forEach(function (k) {
        if (!temp[k]) {
            temp[k] = { _: [] };
            temp._.push({ seriesname: parts[k], data: temp[k]._ });
        }
        temp[k]._.push({ value: a[k] });
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create groups based on month and then you can output the desired data structure. Check the snippet.

```js
var obj = [{
    date: "2017-06-01",
    reqC: "129963",
    month: "JUNE",
    resC: "80522"
  }, {
    date: "2017-06-05",
    reqC: "261162",
    month: "JUNE",
    resC: "83743"
  },{
    date: "2017-07-03",
    reqC: "438860",
    month: "JULY",
    resC: "166107"
  }];

var result = {};

var groups = obj.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  acc[obj.month] = acc[obj.month] || [];
  acc[obj.month].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});

//console.log(groups);

result.dataset = Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) {
  return {
    dataset: [{
      "seriesname" : "Req",   
      "data": groups[key].map(function(o) {
        return { value : o.reqC };
      })
    }, {
      "seriesname" : "Res",   
      "data": groups[key].map(function(o) {
        return { value : o.resC };
      })
    }]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same property name for an object twice. You have an object in your data that looks like this:

```
"data": [
      {
        "value": "80522"
      },
      {
        "value": "83743"
      }
    ]
```

Either change the keys to unique ones:

```
"data": [
      {
        "value1": "80522"
      },
      {
        "value2": "83743"
      }
    ]
```

Or make it an array:

```
"data": [ "80522", "83743" ]
```

Comment: thats properties in 2 different objects, there shouldn't be a problem here

Answer (score 0):

You need to add check for month as well.
Try this:

```
    var obj = [{
    date: "2017-06-01",
    reqC: "129963",
    month: "JUNE",
    resC: "80522"
  }, {
    date: "2017-06-05",
    reqC: "261162",
    month: "JUNE",
    resC: "83743"
  },{
    date: "2017-07-03",
    reqC: "438860",
    month: "JULY",
    resC: "166107"
  }]
  var maindataset = [];

  ["JUNE","JULY"].forEach((month)=>{
  var dataset = [];
     ["reqC", "resC"].forEach((series) => {
      dataset.push({
        seriesname: series,
        data: obj.reduce((filtered, el) => {
          if(el["month"] === month){
           filtered.push({value: el[series]});
           }
           return filtered;
        },[])
      })

    });
    maindataset.push({
      dataset: dataset
    });
  })

  alert(JSON.stringify(maindataset));
```

output:

```
[{
    "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "reqC",
        "data": [{
            "value": "129963"
        }, {
            "value": "261162"
        }]
    }, {
        "seriesname": "resC",
        "data": [{
            "value": "80522"
        }, {
            "value": "83743"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "reqC",
        "data": [{
            "value": "438860"
        }]
    }, {
        "seriesname": "resC",
        "data": [{
            "value": "166107"
        }]
    }]
}]
```